# geocoder undefined method `coordinates='

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On rails 3.2.11, geocoder version 1.1.8

in my model:

```
  class Venue
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid
    ....
    field :address, type: String
    field :latitude, type: Float
    field :longitude, type: Float
    ....

    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
    .....
  end
```

and when I try to create a new venue I get an error traced to the controller at Venue.create

```
undefined method `coordinates=' for #<Venue....
```

To cut to the chase I have run bundle install and restarted the app server since installing the gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc of [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#mongoid), you need this in your model:

```
field :coordinates, :type => Array
```

Geocode need this field to store the geo info(latitude, attitude).